# Shapeless HList Types Extending a Common Trait

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have some types that are based on shapeless HLists:

```
type t1 = Int :: String :: Int :: HNil
type t2 = String :: String :: Int :: HNil
```

I would like to define a sealed trait `ST` that is a super type to all of them so that, if I have the following function:

```
def fun(x:ST) = …
```

the following are valid:

```
fun(5 :: "foo" :: 3 :: HNil)       // It is a t1
fun("foo" :: "bar" :: 42 :: HNil)  // It is a t2
```

but the following does not compile:

```
fun(5 :: 3 :: HNil)
```

How can I define `t1` and `t2` as subtypes of `ST`?

**UPDATE**

I think Coproducts may be a solution

```
type ST = t1 :+: t2 :+: CNil

fun(Coproduct[ST](5 :: "foo" :: 3 :: HNil)) // compiles
fun(Coproduct[ST](5 :: 3 :: HNil))          // does not compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to "make" a type into a subtype of anything using an alias, which is just a new name. While you could use a coproduct, it might be more natural just to create a new type class:

```
import shapeless._

type t1 = Int :: String :: Int :: HNil
type t2 = String :: String :: Int :: HNil

trait Funnable[A]

implicit object t1Funnable extends Funnable[t1]
implicit object t2Funnable extends Funnable[t2]

def fun[A: Funnable](x: A) = x
```

Now the lines you want to compile will, and the one you don't won't.

Comment: Thanks! I adapted it to: `def fun[A <: HList](x:A)(implicit funnable:Funnable[A]) = x` to preserve some type information for `x`

Comment: Great! Note that you can also add the `HList` constraint on the type parameter for the type class itself (that may or may not make sense depending on how you're using this).

Comment: Actually, that's the first thing I tried, but the compiler (Scala 2.10.??) was not able to infer that the function parameter `x` is an HList . In the end, I kept both constraints.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but yes, that's what I meant—that you could put the constraint in both places.